# Find delta of 2 IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I' getting users and groups from active directory, however after some test we found out that `memberOF` is not aligned with `member` example userA is member of groupW but groupW is not listing userA as member. in order to solve this issue we had to get both member and member of then synchronize them.

```
public class User
    {
       public string UserName { get; set; }
       public IList<string> MemberOf { get; set; } // list of group names
    }

public class Group
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<string> Members { get; set; } // list of username
}
```

From active directory i get

```
IEnumerable<Group> allGroups
IEnumerable<User> allUsers
```

How can i get the delta?

I should have 2 Dictionaries or Lookup ..etc

1. allGroups
   list all groups not found in User.MemberOF 
   the dictionary should have the key as groupname and value list of users.

> example groupA users {A,B,C}, GroupB users{A,C}

1. allUsers
   list all users not found in Group.member
   dictionary should have the key as username and the value list of groups.

> example userA groups{x,y}, userB groups{x,z}

Edit: Another example: Let's say that this are the 2 IEnumerable returned from Active directory.

```
 `IEnumerable<Group> allGroups` contains
 - GroupA {"Mike","Jan","David"}
 - GroupB {"Kim","David","Jolan","Tim"}

    // where Groupx is the name of the group and between {""} is the list of member

    IEnumerable<User> allUsers contains

 - Mike {"GroupA","GroupB","GroupC"}
 - David {"GroupA","GroupB"}
 - Jolan {"GroupB","GroupC"}
```

In this example we can see that when we asking LDAP to get all members of groupA "Jolan" is not listed. but when we ask to get all groups where "Jolan" is member then we can see that "GroupA" is listed. Same with "Mike" he is a member of GroupB and also GroupC. GroupC is not listed . "David"
in this case has correct values.

> Also notice that, "Tim" is listed in groupB, although he is not in `allUsers`
>
> Result should be something like this

```
Dictionary<string,IList<string>> missingUsers;
Item 1 > key="Mike", Value={"GroupB","GroupC"}
Item 2 > Key="Jolan" , Value= {"GroupC"}

Dictionary<string,IList<string>> missingGroup;
item 1 > Key="GroupB",{"Tim"}
```

I hope it's more clear

Comment: In your first example are you trying to find the list of users that are **not** in groupA?   IE. A, B, and C are **not** in groupA but all other users **are** in groupA?

Comment: Ok, i will edit the post and try to make it more clear.

Comment: I see... I wasn't expecting LDAP to give inconsistent results like that so that's why I didn't expect that.  Easy to fix... I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you are asking or not... I'll change my answer tomorrow based on your response to my comment.  :)

Assuming you want a dictionary of groups with lists of users who are not in that group, and a dictionary of users with lists of groups they are not in then here is the code for it...

```
    var groupsWithUsersNotInThem = new Dictionary<Group, List<User>>();
    var usersWithGroupsTheyArentIn = new Dictionary<User, List<Group>>();
    allUsers.ForEach(u =>
        {
            var groupsThisUserIsntIn = groups.Where(g => !g.Members.Contains(u.UserName)).ToList();
            if (groupsThisUserIsntIn.Count() > 0)
                usersWithGroupsTheyArentIn.Add(u, groupsThisUserIsntIn);
        });
    allGroups.ForEach(g =>
    {
        var usersNotInThisGroup = users.Where(u => !u.MemberOf.Contains(g.Name)).ToList();
        if (usersNotInThisGroup.Count() > 0)
            groupsWithUsersNotInThem.Add(g, usersNotInThisGroup);
    });
```

**Edit: leaving above code in case it's useful**

Here is the new code that solves the actual delta problem...  it only finds users / groups where the other list doesn't match.

```
    var missingGroups = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
    var missingUsers = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
    allUsers.ForEach(u =>
    {
        // get the list where the group exists but this user isn't in it
        var groupsThisUserIsntIn = allGroups
            .Where(g => u.MemberOf.Contains(g.Name) && !g.Members.Contains(u.UserName))
            .Select(g => g.Name).ToList();
        // add in the groups this user says he belongs to but that aren't in allGroups
        groupsThisUserIsntIn.AddRange(u.MemberOf.Where(userGroupName => allGroups.All(g => g.Name != userGroupName)));
        if (groupsThisUserIsntIn.Count() > 0)
            missingUsers.Add(u.UserName, groupsThisUserIsntIn);
    });
    allGroups.ForEach(g =>
    {
        // get the list where the user exists but this group isn't in it
        var usersNotInThisGroup = allUsers
            .Where(u => g.Members.Contains(u.UserName) && !u.MemberOf.Contains(g.Name))
            .Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
        // add in the users this group says it has but that aren't in allUsers 
        usersNotInThisGroup.AddRange(g.Members.Where(groupUserName => allUsers.All(u => u.UserName != groupUserName)));
        if (usersNotInThisGroup.Count() > 0)
            missingGroups.Add(g.Name, usersNotInThisGroup);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks you Kevin, however it seems that i didn't explain it clearly
However, your solution helped me in another issue, thanks.